# How to eliminate all sources of randomness so that program always gives identical answers?

Tags: c++, random, srand

I have C++ code that relies heavily on sampling (using rand()), but I want it to be reproducible. So in the beginning, I initialize srand() with a random seed and print that seed out. I want others to be able to run the same code again but initializing srand() with that same seed and get exactly the same answer as I did.

But under what circumstances is that guaranteed? I suppose that works only if the binaries are compiled with the same compiler on the same system? What are other factors that might make the answer differ from the one I got initially?

Comment: This is why I love pure code / functional programming.

Comment: Presumably you don't initialise srand() with  a random seed? Or else you are in some infinitely recursive process.

Comment: @Neil Haha, good point, I use a a mixture of clock(), time(NULL) and getpid().

Comment: @strager: Pureness doesn't matter. It's about the implementation of the random number generator.

Comment: Be aware that if your code is multithreaded, seeding the random number generator isn't going to take out all your nondeterminism.  Other issues would be systems running out of memory, floating-point arithmetic differences, anything involving getting the current time or hostname...

Comment: @Borealid  Please expand on that. I don't see what MT has to do with the problem.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: If a program is multithreaded, the order of thread interleaving (which is nondeterministic) can affect its output.  Also true of interprocess communication, networked message passing, shared memory access...  Because running the same program twice can have two different outcomes due to scheduler fickleness, your program is not deterministic anymore once you make it parallel.

Comment: @Borealid The output of the generator is still deterministic - it simply happens in different threads.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: Thread A: `x = 1; y = x+1; print y;`.  Thread B: `y = 1; x = y+1; print x;`.  This program can produce many different results, but consists only of two deterministic threads.  You'll probably get different output each time you run it.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth:  It doesn't matter if the generator produces the same sequence of numbers if the way you use them is different.

Comment: @Neil: I think his concerns about multi-threaded programs are important, and even more so his hint at floating-point arithmetic differences in different systems. I was specifically interested in these "other factors" that can make the output of a different run different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is to use the same code in all cases - the Boost random number library is infinitely better than any C++ standard library implementation, and you  can use the same code on all platforms. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254909/boost-random-number-generator) for example of its use and links to the library docs.

Comment: I see. So if I tell others to include the, say, Boost 1.42 random number generator that I used and initialize with the same seed that I used then they will get the exactly same result? Even on other platforms and using another compiler?

Comment: I'd add that it is correct only if you take the numbers in the same way everytime. Like another mentionned in the comments: if your using the same number generator for multiple threads, for exemple, the result might not be reproducible.

Answer (score 3):

You're correct that the sequences might be different if compiled on different machines with different `rand` implementations. The best way to get around this is to write your own PRNG. The Linux man page for `srand` gives the following simple example (quoted from the POSIX standard):

> POSIX.1-2001  gives the following
>   example of an implementation of rand()
>   and srand(), possibly useful when one
>   needs the same sequence on two
>   different machines.

```
 static unsigned long next = 1;

 /* RAND_MAX assumed to be 32767 */
 int myrand(void) {
     next = next * 1103515245 + 12345;
     return((unsigned)(next/65536) % 32768);
 }

 void mysrand(unsigned seed) {
     next = seed;
 }
```

Comment: Writing your own RNG is the last possible alternative you should consider. There is probably no other functionality it is so easy to get wrong and so difficult to test for correctness.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this kind of problem, write your own implementation of `rand()`!  I'm no expert on random-number generation algorithms, so I'll say no more than that...

Comment: Yeah, just solve again what thousands did before. That's the True C Programmer's approach. :P

Answer (score 0):

Check out [implementation of rand()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167253/implementation-of-rand), and use one of the random number generators from there - which ensures repeatability no matter what platform you run on.